# Assume that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L.$ Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^3) = L.$ Is this proof sufficient?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Assume that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L.$ Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}
> > f(x^3) = L$

Here's my attempt using an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument:

> Since $lim_{x\to0}f(x) = L$, we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta: 0< |x - 0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$
>
> Let $x = a^3$ and we have $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta: 0< |a^3 - 0| < \delta \implies |f(a^3) - L| < \epsilon$
>
> Thus, there exists $\delta' = \sqrt[3]{\delta}$ such that $0 < |a - 0| < \delta' \implies 0 < |a^3 - 0| < \delta \implies |f(a^3) - L| < \epsilon, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0$
>
> It follows that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x^3) = \lim_{a\to0} f(a^3) = L.$

Here's my other attempt that I'm not sure is acceptable.

> As $x$ tends to $0$, $x^3$ tends to $0$, so $\lim_{x\to0} f(x^3) = \lim_{x^3\to0} f(x^3)$.
>
> Let $a = x^3$ and we have $\lim_{x^3\to0} f(x^3) = \lim_{a\to0} f(a) = L$, so $\lim_{x\to0} f(x^3) = L$.

For some reason, I'm not confident about my 2nd argument. Please let me know if it's acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: $\forall |x|<1, |x^3|<|x|$.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Pardon but I'm not sure what you mean. Is it a problem in the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof? I never compared $|x|$ and $|x^3|$ so I'm a bit confused by your comment. Since $|a| < \delta'$, with both being positive numbers, I believe we can cube both sides and get $|a^3| < (\delta')^3 = \delta$, but I'm not sure this is the point you were referring to though.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen I see! Sorry if I'm slow but is it a hint to an entirely new proof, or is it a hint to where the 2nd proof could fall apart?

Comment: Go back to your manipulations. Starts with "Let $\epsilon >0"$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first argument is good, but perhaps a more 'elegant' $\delta'$ to choose, as @StéphaneJaouen points out, is $\delta' = \min \{1, \delta\}$, where $\delta > 0$ is chosen such that $\forall x$: $0 < |x|<\delta \implies |f(x) - L|< \varepsilon.$  Then when $0 < |x| < \delta'$, we have both $|x| < 1$ (hence $|x^3| \leq |x|$) and $|x| < \delta$, and so $$0 < |x^3| \leq |x| < \delta$$ which you know implies that $|f(x^3) - L| < \varepsilon.$

This is something that often occurs in an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof: if you know something is true about 'small enough' $|x-a|$ (like less than 1) you can force $\delta'$ to be at most $1$ using such a minimum. Do not be afraid to use it!

The second argument works *if* you understand why. If $\lim_{a \to 0} g(a) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$, then you should be able to prove using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definitions that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x)) = L$. Try this! (Here we assume $g(a) \neq 0$ for all $a \neq 0$ sufficiently small.)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! The first remark is very useful and it gave me an idea to improve a limit proof that I did earlier today. On your 2nd remark, yes I did a generalized version of this a while ago (marked as the composition rule in my textbook). It seems the 2nd argument still needs to be backed by an epsilon-delta argument after all.

Comment: But now that I think about it, I realize it does make sense using epsilon-delta for caution since I was equating $x\rightarrow0$ with $g(x)\rightarrow0$ in my 2nd proof, which could break down in a different argument like $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = lim_{g(x)\to0} f(x)$ since $g(x)$ tends to $0$ could be due to $x$ tending to a value other than $0.$

Comment: @ten_to_tenth If you can use the composition rule in your Textbook that would be preferable. Always be careful that the conditions are met before you apply a theorem. It's usually in two flavors: you have a statement about $f,g$ with $f$ continuous and a statement about general $f,g$. Here it is not a priori given that $f$ is continuous and then it could break down if $g$ is constantly 0 near $x = 0$. Of course for us this is not a problem since $x^3 \neq 0$ when $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @ten_to_tenth I have a question for you: find an $f$ and $g$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ (I took $ L = 0$ for simplicity) and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$, but also $\lim_{x\to 0} f(g(x)) \neq 0$ ...

Comment: Hmm I believe we just need to find $f$ such that it is discontinuous at $L.$ How about $g(x)$ = 0 and $f(x) = x$ if $x \neq 0$ and $1$ if $x = 0$? Then $\lim_{x\to0} f(g(x)) = lim_{x\to0} f(0) = 1 \neq 0$ while the other 2 limits are both $0$.

Comment: @ten_to_tenth Yes that's it! That's the only thing that can go wrong in the argument, but $x^3$ isn't constantly 0 near 0 so we're okay :D

Comment: Thank you very much!